Can I equip more than just armor, elytra, mob heads, and turtle shells?
I've seen this page on the Minecraft Wiki where Steve and Alex are wearing items on their head and face.
For example, this image of Steve wearing an end rod:

I noticed that the wiki says that it specifically needs the spy glass and lighting rod. Does that mean that I can't wear something like a log on my head using the command it provided? I haven't played in awhile, but I would choose ver. 1.21.1.

The solution is probably something with the /item command. Definitely not possible in Survival. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/item

@FabianRöling I know about the /item command and would need it to do weird things, I was just wondering what other blocks and items can be used as equipment?

You can equip any item on your head using the item replace command
Using the following command, you can equip any item in the game on to your head slot:
/item replace entity @p armor.head with minecraft:[Item]

So if you wanted to equip an end rod, you would type:
/item replace entity @p armor.head with minecraft:end_rod

This works in both Version 1.21.1, as well as the most recent 1.21.3. And as this is a command, this of course only works if you enable commands/cheats in your world, which is enabled by default in a Creative world and disabled in a Survival world.
Depending on the item you choose, there are three possible ways the item will display (excluding items you can equip normally):

Items with a custom appearance. Some items, like the end rod, spyglass or lightning rod you mentioned will display in a certain, often times humorous way. Those three will make your player look like a unicorn. Other examples are bones being held in your mouth like a dog or holding a raw cod like a cellphone. A full list can be found here on the wiki.


Blocks. Any block will appear fully covering your head.


Non-Blocks. Anythying else, e.g. Boats, Minecarts, End Crystals, will appear behind your head.



Though some blocks/items such as buttons, will be too small to be visible, as your head will fully conceal them.

One more thing to note: This only works for the head slot, if you try to equip anything, that isn't normally equippable in your other Armor slots (e.g. armor.chest), you will get error messages.


On the first image with the bone in your mouth, I noticed that you got a new recipe for bonemeal because of the bone in your mouth. Talk about bonemeal.

Now I can cause havoc and confusion in a friend's world just by wearing things on my head if I wanted to, lol.
